# Drupal db_query get all rows

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I'm starting to build themes for Drupal.

I have a question about drupal queries, but I didn't find any answer...

I have a db_query in one of my modules, but only return a few rows (13 rows always, and table has 20) How can I select all rows from one table?

My query is like this

```
$result = db_query("SELECT * FROM bv_calendar c INNER JOIN bv_countries p ON c.country_id = p.country_id INNER JOIN bv_vaccinate v ON c.vaccinate_id = v.vaccinate_id ORDER BY $orderby ASC");

while ($class = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $classes[$class["calendar_id"]] = $class;
}
```

How can I get all rows?

Thank you

Comment: You may have rows in your FROM table which have no correspondency in one or both the joint tables. Try with LEFT JOIN, and be aware that this is not really a Drupal question.

Comment: You right, I've spent so much time on this! Thanks for your "eyes"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it I'd say you're not getting all the rows from the *bv_calendar* because you're using **INNER JOIN** on your SQL query which requires to be matching records on your *bv_countries* and *bv_vaccinate* tables.

Try replacing the **INNER JOIN** for **LEFT JOIN** as in the later "*If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for the right table.*" from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html.

If that's the result you want then your SQL query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM bv_calendar c LEFT JOIN bv_countries p ON c.country_id = p.country_id LEFT JOIN bv_vaccinate v ON c.vaccinate_id = v.vaccinate_id ORDER BY $orderby ASC
```